# Trying to run a simple dash and it returns and error

Tags: python, dashboard

I am trying to get a simple dashboard up and running but I am running into an error:

The code:

```
import dash
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Hi Dash'),
    html.Div('Dash - a dashboard')
])
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(port=4050)
```

I run this on a Jupyter Notebook and also on a VS code editor running python 3.9.12 on OpenSuse leap.

The error:

```
Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

 * Serving Flask app '__main__'
 * Debug mode: off

Name or service not known

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py:911, in prepare_socket(hostname, port)
    910 try:
--> 911     s.bind(server_address)
    912 except OSError as e:

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

Cell In [8], line 2
      1 if __name__=='__main__':
----> 2     app.run_server(port=4050)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dash.py:2128, in Dash.run_server(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2123 """`run_server` is a deprecated alias of `run` and may be removed in a
   2124 future version. We recommend using `app.run` instead.
   2125 
   2126 See `app.run` for usage information.
   2127 """
-> 2128 self.run(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dash.py:1961, in Dash.run(self, host, port, proxy, debug, dev_tools_ui, dev_tools_props_check, dev_tools_serve_dev_bundles, dev_tools_hot_reload, dev_tools_hot_reload_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_watch_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_max_retry, dev_tools_silence_routes_logging, dev_tools_prune_errors, **flask_run_options)
   1959             extra_files.append(path)
-> 1961 self.server.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:1188, in Flask.run(self, host, port, debug, load_dotenv, **options)
   1187 try:
-> 1188     run_simple(t.cast(str, host), port, self, **options)
   1189 finally:
   1190     # reset the first request information if the development server
   1191     # reset normally.  This makes it possible to restart the server
   1192     # without reloader and that stuff from an interactive shell.

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py:1062, in run_simple(hostname, port, application, use_reloader, use_debugger, use_evalex, extra_files, exclude_patterns, reloader_interval, reloader_type, threaded, processes, request_handler, static_files, passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
   1061 if not is_running_from_reloader():
-> 1062     s = prepare_socket(hostname, port)
   1063     fd = s.fileno()

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py:930, in prepare_socket(hostname, port)
    924             print(
    925                 "On macOS, try disabling the 'AirPlay Receiver'"
    926                 " service from System Preferences -> Sharing.",
    927                 file=sys.stderr,
    928             )
--> 930     sys.exit(1)
    932 s.listen(LISTEN_QUEUE)

SystemExit: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:1987, in InteractiveShell.showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   1984 if exception_only:
   1985     stb = ['An exception has occurred, use %tb to see '
   1986            'the full traceback.\n']
-> 1987     stb.extend(self.InteractiveTB.get_exception_only(etype,
   1988                                                      value))
   1989 else:
   1990     try:
   1991         # Exception classes can customise their traceback - we
   1992         # use this in IPython.parallel for exceptions occurring
   1993         # in the engines. This should return a list of strings.

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:579, in ListTB.get_exception_only(self, etype, value)
    571 def get_exception_only(self, etype, value):
    572     """Only print the exception type and message, without a traceback.
    573 
    574     Parameters
   (...)
    577     value : exception value
    578     """
--> 579     return ListTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, value)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:446, in ListTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, evalue, etb, tb_offset, context)
    443     chained_exc_ids.add(id(exception[1]))
    444     chained_exceptions_tb_offset = 0
    445     out_list = (
--> 446         self.structured_traceback(
    447             etype, evalue, (etb, chained_exc_ids),
    448             chained_exceptions_tb_offset, context)
    449         + chained_exception_message
    450         + out_list)
    452 return out_list

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:1112, in AutoFormattedTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1110 else:
   1111     self.tb = tb
-> 1112 return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
   1113     self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:1006, in FormattedTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1003 mode = self.mode
   1004 if mode in self.verbose_modes:
   1005     # Verbose modes need a full traceback
-> 1006     return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
   1007         self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
   1008     )
   1009 elif mode == 'Minimal':
   1010     return ListTB.get_exception_only(self, etype, value)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:859, in VerboseTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, evalue, etb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
    850 def structured_traceback(
    851     self,
    852     etype: type,
   (...)
    856     number_of_lines_of_context: int = 5,
    857 ):
    858     """Return a nice text document describing the traceback."""
--> 859     formatted_exception = self.format_exception_as_a_whole(etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context,
    860                                                            tb_offset)
    862     colors = self.Colors  # just a shorthand + quicker name lookup
    863     colorsnormal = colors.Normal  # used a lot

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:793, in VerboseTB.format_exception_as_a_whole(self, etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
    790 assert isinstance(tb_offset, int)
    791 head = self.prepare_header(etype, self.long_header)
    792 records = (
--> 793     self.get_records(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset) if etb else []
    794 )
    796 frames = []
    797 skipped = 0

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:848, in VerboseTB.get_records(self, etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
    842     formatter = None
    843 options = stack_data.Options(
    844     before=before,
    845     after=after,
    846     pygments_formatter=formatter,
    847 )
--> 848 return list(stack_data.FrameInfo.stack_data(etb, options=options))[tb_offset:]

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/core.py:578, in FrameInfo.stack_data(cls, frame_or_tb, options, collapse_repeated_frames)
    562 @classmethod
    563 def stack_data(
    564         cls,
   (...)
    568         collapse_repeated_frames: bool = True
    569 ) -> Iterator[Union['FrameInfo', RepeatedFrames]]:
    570     """
    571     An iterator of FrameInfo and RepeatedFrames objects representing
    572     a full traceback or stack. Similar consecutive frames are collapsed into RepeatedFrames
   (...)
    576     and optionally an Options object to configure.
    577     """
--> 578     stack = list(iter_stack(frame_or_tb))
    580     # Reverse the stack from a frame so that it's in the same order
    581     # as the order from a traceback, which is the order of a printed
    582     # traceback when read top to bottom (most recent call last)
    583     if is_frame(frame_or_tb):

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py:98, in iter_stack(frame_or_tb)
     96 while frame_or_tb:
     97     yield frame_or_tb
---> 98     if is_frame(frame_or_tb):
     99         frame_or_tb = frame_or_tb.f_back
    100     else:

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py:91, in is_frame(frame_or_tb)
     90 def is_frame(frame_or_tb: Union[FrameType, TracebackType]) -> bool:
---> 91     assert_(isinstance(frame_or_tb, (types.FrameType, types.TracebackType)))
     92     return isinstance(frame_or_tb, (types.FrameType,))

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py:172, in assert_(condition, error)
    170 if isinstance(error, str):
    171     error = AssertionError(error)
--> 172 raise error

AssertionError:
```

EDIT:

I add `debug=True` and this is my output:

```
Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

Dash is running on http://localhost.localdomain:4050/

 * Serving Flask app '__main__'
 * Debug mode: on

Name or service not known

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py:911, in prepare_socket(hostname, port)
    910 try:
--> 911     s.bind(server_address)
    912 except OSError as e:

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

Cell In [11], line 8
      7 if __name__=='__main__':
----> 8     app.run_server(port=4050, debug=True)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dash.py:2128, in Dash.run_server(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2123 """`run_server` is a deprecated alias of `run` and may be removed in a
   2124 future version. We recommend using `app.run` instead.
   2125 
   2126 See `app.run` for usage information.
   2127 """
-> 2128 self.run(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dash.py:1961, in Dash.run(self, host, port, proxy, debug, dev_tools_ui, dev_tools_props_check, dev_tools_serve_dev_bundles, dev_tools_hot_reload, dev_tools_hot_reload_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_watch_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_max_retry, dev_tools_silence_routes_logging, dev_tools_prune_errors, **flask_run_options)
   1959             extra_files.append(path)
-> 1961 self.server.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:1188, in Flask.run(self, host, port, debug, load_dotenv, **options)
   1187 try:
-> 1188     run_simple(t.cast(str, host), port, self, **options)
   1189 finally:
   1190     # reset the first request information if the development server
   1191     # reset normally.  This makes it possible to restart the server
   1192     # without reloader and that stuff from an interactive shell.

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py:1062, in run_simple(hostname, port, application, use_reloader, use_debugger, use_evalex, extra_files, exclude_patterns, reloader_interval, reloader_type, threaded, processes, request_handler, static_files, passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
   1061 if not is_running_from_reloader():
-> 1062     s = prepare_socket(hostname, port)
   1063     fd = s.fileno()

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py:930, in prepare_socket(hostname, port)
    924             print(
    925                 "On macOS, try disabling the 'AirPlay Receiver'"
    926                 " service from System Preferences -> Sharing.",
    927                 file=sys.stderr,
    928             )
--> 930     sys.exit(1)
    932 s.listen(LISTEN_QUEUE)

SystemExit: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:1987, in InteractiveShell.showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   1984 if exception_only:
   1985     stb = ['An exception has occurred, use %tb to see '
   1986            'the full traceback.\n']
-> 1987     stb.extend(self.InteractiveTB.get_exception_only(etype,
   1988                                                      value))
   1989 else:
   1990     try:
   1991         # Exception classes can customise their traceback - we
   1992         # use this in IPython.parallel for exceptions occurring
   1993         # in the engines. This should return a list of strings.

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:579, in ListTB.get_exception_only(self, etype, value)
    571 def get_exception_only(self, etype, value):
    572     """Only print the exception type and message, without a traceback.
    573 
    574     Parameters
   (...)
    577     value : exception value
    578     """
--> 579     return ListTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, value)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:446, in ListTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, evalue, etb, tb_offset, context)
    443     chained_exc_ids.add(id(exception[1]))
    444     chained_exceptions_tb_offset = 0
    445     out_list = (
--> 446         self.structured_traceback(
    447             etype, evalue, (etb, chained_exc_ids),
    448             chained_exceptions_tb_offset, context)
    449         + chained_exception_message
    450         + out_list)
    452 return out_list

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:1112, in AutoFormattedTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1110 else:
   1111     self.tb = tb
-> 1112 return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
   1113     self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:1006, in FormattedTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1003 mode = self.mode
   1004 if mode in self.verbose_modes:
   1005     # Verbose modes need a full traceback
-> 1006     return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
   1007         self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
   1008     )
   1009 elif mode == 'Minimal':
   1010     return ListTB.get_exception_only(self, etype, value)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:859, in VerboseTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, evalue, etb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
    850 def structured_traceback(
    851     self,
    852     etype: type,
   (...)
    856     number_of_lines_of_context: int = 5,
    857 ):
    858     """Return a nice text document describing the traceback."""
--> 859     formatted_exception = self.format_exception_as_a_whole(etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context,
    860                                                            tb_offset)
    862     colors = self.Colors  # just a shorthand + quicker name lookup
    863     colorsnormal = colors.Normal  # used a lot

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:793, in VerboseTB.format_exception_as_a_whole(self, etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
    790 assert isinstance(tb_offset, int)
    791 head = self.prepare_header(etype, self.long_header)
    792 records = (
--> 793     self.get_records(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset) if etb else []
    794 )
    796 frames = []
    797 skipped = 0

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py:848, in VerboseTB.get_records(self, etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
    842     formatter = None
    843 options = stack_data.Options(
    844     before=before,
    845     after=after,
    846     pygments_formatter=formatter,
    847 )
--> 848 return list(stack_data.FrameInfo.stack_data(etb, options=options))[tb_offset:]

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/core.py:578, in FrameInfo.stack_data(cls, frame_or_tb, options, collapse_repeated_frames)
    562 @classmethod
    563 def stack_data(
    564         cls,
   (...)
    568         collapse_repeated_frames: bool = True
    569 ) -> Iterator[Union['FrameInfo', RepeatedFrames]]:
    570     """
    571     An iterator of FrameInfo and RepeatedFrames objects representing
    572     a full traceback or stack. Similar consecutive frames are collapsed into RepeatedFrames
   (...)
    576     and optionally an Options object to configure.
    577     """
--> 578     stack = list(iter_stack(frame_or_tb))
    580     # Reverse the stack from a frame so that it's in the same order
    581     # as the order from a traceback, which is the order of a printed
    582     # traceback when read top to bottom (most recent call last)
    583     if is_frame(frame_or_tb):

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py:98, in iter_stack(frame_or_tb)
     96 while frame_or_tb:
     97     yield frame_or_tb
---> 98     if is_frame(frame_or_tb):
     99         frame_or_tb = frame_or_tb.f_back
    100     else:

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py:91, in is_frame(frame_or_tb)
     90 def is_frame(frame_or_tb: Union[FrameType, TracebackType]) -> bool:
---> 91     assert_(isinstance(frame_or_tb, (types.FrameType, types.TracebackType)))
     92     return isinstance(frame_or_tb, (types.FrameType,))

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py:172, in assert_(condition, error)
    170 if isinstance(error, str):
    171     error = AssertionError(error)
--> 172 raise error

AssertionError:
```

Comment: You didn't actually provide any code. Please provide a [mre]. It's likely that whatever `server_address` you used was invalid.

Comment: Ah you are right, I thought I did, I will do so now!

Comment: Is `localhost.localdomain` a valid DNS entry in your environment? `locahost` by itself should be fine but adding `.localdomain` will cause the `bind()` method to attempt to resolve a potentially unknown hostname. Did you create that hostname or is dash creating it automatically?

Comment: Not 100% sure to be honest. I was playing around with Flask previously so I am not sure if that has changed some settings... I am / was able to get Flash running. How can I check if `localhost.localdomain` is a valid DNS entry in the enviroment?

Comment: AFAIK `localhost.localdomain` is a RedHat Linux thing. Outside of that environment it's just another domain name that won't exist unless you put it in your /etc/hosts. (`.local` is special-cased to use mDNS, but `.localdomain` isn't even a valid TLD.)

Comment: You could always edit your `/etc/hosts` for your environment and map `localhost.localdomain` to your loopback address. Though there should be a way to specify the domain or a default route `0.0.0.0` to Dash / Flask.

Comment: Try `app.run_server(port=4050,host="0.0.0.0")`. Dash appears to use Flask under the hood. Whenever I launch a Flask app locally I typically just do `app.run(host="0.0.0.0")`

Comment: Thanks, running `app.run_server(port=4050,host="0.0.0.0")` works.